# IE11: Text of input field slips below the bottom border

Tags: html, css, sass, internet-explorer-11

Recently I noticed that some of my code which works well in browsers like chrome or firefox makes the internet explorer do some strange things. 
One of these things is the following:
I have a page with three input fields. The inputs are displayed correctly but when I type something the value slips below the bottom border.
Another minor bug is that the three little buttons at the bottom should be in one line. But in IE the fast forward button is broken to the next line.
I couldn't find any code that might not work in IE11. Any ideas?

*For some reason I failed to reproduce the thing on sites like jsfiddle. That's why I also attached pictures.*

```css
$inputFontSize: 8vw;
//Verhindern, dass Inputfeld eingerahmt wird, wenn es den Fokus erhält.
*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("https://ibin.co/w800/4JgKBfiSuGat.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-size: cover;
}

#buttons {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5%;
  z-index: 20;
  width: 100%;
}

.control-buttons {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border-color: black !important;
  color: black !important;
}

#faster-div {
  display: contents;
}

#foreground-mountains {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20%;
  background: url("https://ibin.co/4JgKSDfGvPRf.png") no-repeat;
}

#dreieck-inner {
  position: relative;
}

.result-empty {
  border: none !important;
}

.result-correct {
  border: solid 3px green !important;
}

.result-false {
  border: solid 3px red !important;
}


/* Rechts unten */

#input3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: $inputFontSize;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  border: none;
  right: 22%;
  bottom: 15%;
}


/* Links unten */

#input2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: $inputFontSize;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  border: none;
  left: 18%;
  bottom: 15%;
}


/* Oben */

#input1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 20%;
  font-size: $inputFontSize;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  border: none;
  right: 42%;
  top: 35%;
}

#rowDisplay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 250%;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 35%;
}

.topOperator {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 37%;
  bottom: 33%;
  font-size: 500%;
}

.bottomOperator {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 17%;
  font-size: 500%;
}

#timer {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 250%;
  left: 43%;
  top: 10%;
}

#dreieck-container {
  background-image: url("https://ibin.co/w800/4JgKmVu4ZYX1.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  
      $dc-height: 700px;
    height: $dc-height;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: calc(#{$dc-height} * 1.46);
    left: 20%;
    bottom: 5%;
}

/*@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  #dreieck-container {
    $dc-height: 700px;
    height: $dc-height;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: calc(#{$dc-height} * 1.46);
    left: 20%;
    bottom: 5%;
  }
}*/
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="dreieck-container">
    <div class="dreieck">
      <div class="dreieck-inner">
        <span class="clickable" id="timer"></span>

        <input id="input1" type="text">

        <span id="operator"></span>

        <input id="input2" type="text">
        <input id="input3" type="text">

        <div id="buttons">
          <button id="pauseButton" class="btn btn-primary control-buttons">
                        <i class="far fa-pause-circle"></i>
                    </button>
          <button id="continueButton" class="btn btn-primary control-buttons">
                        <i class="far fa-play-circle"></i>
                    </button>
          <div id="faster-div">
            <button id="fasterButton" class="btn btn-primary control-buttons">
                            <i class="fas fa-fast-forward"></i>
                        </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span id="score"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="foreground-mountains"></div>
</div>
```

That's how it looks like on IE11:
[image]

Comment: "_Recently I noticed that some of my code which works well in browsers like chrome or firefox makes the internet explorer do some strange things_" Welcome to web programming bud :)

Comment: You should look into doing a CSS reset if you don't have one already. The default padding & margins for browsers can cause this sort of thing. Inspect those numbers and I'll bet you'll see margin or padding from the user agent as the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Jacob for your great hint.
There was indeed some UA specific style but it wasn't padding or margin.
I had to set `line-height: normal;`.

Comment: I try to run your code but it is not exact what we can see in image. Its like incomplete code. https://i.postimg.cc/C1xP9hgk/11.png  Can you post the screenshot of inspect element from developer tools may help us to find the cause for the issue.